# Change android toolbar background color alone

Tags: android, toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res`enter code here`/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
```

When i try to set toolbar alpha value as 0 at runtime it also hides the toolbar icons.

i need to set the toolbar background color as red at runtime with dynamic alpha.

please help me to fix  this.

Comment: @BidhanA can you understand my issue now.. icannot post question im blocked..